# Upgrading Ruby 1.9.2 to 1.9.3 Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I had ruby `1.9.2` previously installed, and now I would like to upgrade it to version `1.9.3` so that I can install Rails, but I keep getting this error:

```
ruby-1.9.3-p484 - #downloading rubygems-2.2.2

There is no checksum for 'http://production.cf.rubygems.org/rubygems/rubygems-2.2.2.tgz'     
for 'rubygems-2.2.2.tgz', it's not possible to validate it.
This could be because your RVM install's list of versions is out of date. You may want to
update your list of rubies by running 'rvm get stable' and try again.
If that does not resolve the issue and you wish to continue with unverified download
add '--verify-downloads 1' after the command.
```

I have already tried:

- `rvm get stable`
- `rvm get head`
- `gem update --system`

yet I still get the same error. I am using `JewelryBox` to install version `1.9.3`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

To Install RVM

```
\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
```

Then

```
rvm install 1.9.3 --with-gcc=clang
```

Comment: I ended up uninstalling and reinstalling everything. Thank you for your input though!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command:

```
rvm install 1.9.3 --verify-downloads 1
```